# returning outer fn after async inner function returns [ui-router and htmlservice]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-apps-script, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to work ui-router with client-side js HtmlService in apps script. After exhaustive tries, I'm stuck with simple js problem

```
.state('state1', {
        url: base+'?page=state1_KB',
        views: {
                'content':{
                     template: 
                     function(){
                         google.script.run.withFailureHandler(notemp).withSuccessHandler(temp).include(obj); 

                         function temp(view){
                             console.log(view); //This logs successfully.
                             return view; //This works too I suppose
                           }
                         return temp(view); //This doesn't work obviously
                        },
                     controller: 'state1Controller'
                  }
                 }
    })
```

`include(obj)` fetches the template and gives it back to `temp(view)`. I need to return the value from `temp(view)`. But obviously it's not gonna return anything.

How to return the outer function after `temp(view)` has been called by `google.script.run`?

*For pure JS enthusiast*, I guess it's quite similar to this:

```
function outer(){
  var a = "b";
  setTimeout(function(){console.log("this is Log"); a = 'c';}, 2000);
  return a;
}
```

*From ui-router or angular perspective*, is there something simpler that I could do to achieve what I'm trying here?

Comment: What do you think is the value returned by outer() in your second example?

Comment: for the js example I gave, it should be "b".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
    templateProvider: 
             function($q){
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        var temp = function(view){
                             console.log(view);
                             deferred.resolve(view);
                        }
                        google.script.run
                                .withFailureHandler(notemp)
                                .withSuccessHandler(temp)
                                .include(obj);

                        return deferred.promise;
                     },
                     controller: 'state1Controller'
                  }
```